# Why is this a python syntax error during an initialisation?

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

This code:

```
class Todo:
    def addto(self, list_name="", text=""):
        """
        Adds an item to the specified list.
        """
        if list_name == "":
            list_name = sys.argv[2]
            text = ''.join(sys.argv[3:]

        todo_list = TodoList(getListFilename(list_name))
```

produces a syntax error with the little arrow pointing to `todo_list` on the last line.

The `__init__` method for `TodoList` is here:

```
def __init__(self, json_location):
    """
    Sets up the list.
    """
    self.json_location = json_location
    self.load()
```

I am kind of new to Python, so I don't see what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to close this )

```
text = ''.join(sys.argv[3:]
```

Comment: *Epic facepalm*. Note to self: Interpreter is not very accurate at locating syntax errors. Check in more detail next time.

Comment: @Macha: Actually, it's deadly accurate locating the syntax errors.  Don't let your assumptions about previous lines of code cloud your interpretation of the error message.  The statement -- without the closing `)` can continue on until it's clear that some punctuation is missing.